# How to call a variable within a function in a R script from a R mark down file?

Tags: r, function, global

I have a R script named 'measure.R'. In that script i have defined following function,

```
calculate <- function(velocity, time){
  distance <- velocity * time
  .........
  .........
}
```

Now I want to call the variable 'distance' from the function 'calculate' in the scripte 'measure.R' from a R mark down file. How to do that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the variable 'distance' from the function 'calculate'"? `distance` is only defined within the scope of `calculate`. So even if you `source` "measure.R" from within your Rmd file, `distance` will not be available from within the global scope. Perhaps you want to modify `calculate` to return `distance` as well, e.g. have `calculate` return `list(distance = distance, ... = ...)`? Then `calculate(velocity = ..., time = ...)$distance` will give you `distance`.

Answer (score 0):

Try ,

```r
calculate <- function(velocity, time){
       distance <<- velocity * time 
}

calculate(12,3)

distance
#> [1] 36
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is not a good solution/example. The superassignment operator `<<-` should not be used to modify variables in the global scope. In fact, I would advise against using the superassignment operator at all unless you really know what you’re doing. In this case it is better to have `calculate` return `distance` (and whatever else the function needs to return).